# Filter through pagination angular

Tags: json, django, angularjs

```js
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.filter('offset', function() {
  return function(input, start) {
    start = parseInt(start, 10);
    return input.slice(start);
  };
});

app.controller("MyControler", function($scope, $http, $filter) {
      $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/cars/?format=json").
        success(function(data) {
              $scope.list = data;
          });

  $scope.itemsPerPage = 7;
  $scope.currentPage = 0;
  $scope.items = [];

  for (var i=0; i<50; i++) {
    $scope.items.push({ id: i, name: "name "+ i, description: "description " + i });
  }

  $scope.range = function() {
    var rangeSize = 5;
    var ret = [];
    var start;

    start = $scope.currentPage;
    if ( start > $scope.pageCount()-rangeSize ) {
      start = $scope.pageCount()-rangeSize+1;
    }

    for (var i=start; i<start+rangeSize; i++) {
      ret.push(i);
    }
    return ret;
  };

  $scope.prevPage = function() {
    if ($scope.currentPage > 0) {
      $scope.currentPage--;
    }
  };

  $scope.prevPageDisabled = function() {
    return $scope.currentPage === 0 ? "disabled" : "";
  };

  $scope.pageCount = function() {
    return Math.ceil($scope.list.length/ $scope.itemsPerPage)-1;
  };

  $scope.nextPage = function() {
    if ($scope.currentPage < $scope.pageCount()) {
      $scope.currentPage++;
    }
  };

  $scope.nextPageDisabled = function() {
    return $scope.currentPage === $scope.pageCount() ? "disabled" : "";
  };

  $scope.setPage = function(n) {
    $scope.currentPage = n;
  };


  var filterBy = $filter('offset'); $scope.$watch('search', function (newValue) { $scope.list = filterBy($scope.cars, newValue); }, true);

});
```

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
        {% load staticfiles %}
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>



</head>
<body>

{% verbatim %}

  <div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyControler">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
            <tr>
        <th><input ng-model="search.name" ></th>
        <th><input ng-model="search.years"></th>
        <th><input ng-model="search.owners"></th>
        <th><input ng-model="search.accidents"></th>
        <th><input ng-model="search.description"></th>
    </tr>
        <tr>

          <th>Name</th>
              <th>Years</th>
          <th>Owners</th>
              <th>Accidents</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="cars in list | offset: currentPage*itemsPerPage | limitTo: itemsPerPage| filter:search ">

          <td>{{cars.name}}</td>
          <td>{{cars.years}}</td>

          <td>{{cars.owners}}</td>
          <td>{{cars.accidents}}</td>

          <td>{{cars.description}}</td>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <td colspan="3">
          <div class="pagination">
            <ul>
              <li ng-class="prevPageDisabled()">
                <a href ng-click="prevPage()">« Prev</a>
              </li>
              <li ng-repeat="n in range()" ng-class="{active: n == currentPage}" ng-click="setPage(n)">
                <a href="#">{{n+1}}</a>
              </li>
              <li ng-class="nextPageDisabled()">
                <a href ng-click="nextPage()">Next »</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>







{% endverbatim %}
</body>

 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/app2.js' %}"></script>
</html>
```

I found some issue about this on stackoverflow but i still doing sth wrong, i want to search through all pages, but filter search only through active page, i thought mayby it is because watch search so i change on search.name or sth, still the same,

I am fresh to angular so mayby sb could just tell me where should i look to repair my code

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your filter before the offset/limit so that you are paging on the search results, not searching on the page results.

```
<tr ng-repeat="cars in list | filter:search | offset: currentPage*itemsPerPage | limitTo: itemsPerPage ">
```

Comment: Everything fine  now ;), i have to use logic more often, once more huge thanks ;)